# Creating a class decorator that decorator that is a class itself

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators, python-class

I need a decorator with a static variable, which is basically a counter. So it needs to be a class because we don't seem to have static variables in python.
From the code it's probably clear what I'm trying to do.

```
class decorator_class:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self,cls,*args,**kwargs):
        self.cls,self.args,self.kwargs=cls,args,kwargs
    def __call__(self):
        t1 = time.time()
        instance=self.cls()
        t2 = time.time()
        print('It took: {}'.format(t2 - t1))
        self.counter=self.counter+(t2-t1)
        print('Total time: {}'.format(self.counter))

        return(instance)

class Target:
    def __init__():
        print("Target running")

decorator_class(Target)()
```

The above does not work.

It is also required that the class `Target` can have arguments in its `__init__` constructor.

Comment: Sorry the title is a bit of a mess. It should've been "Creating a decorator that is a class and that decorates classes"

Comment: You don't need a class for this kind of behavior, what you're looking for is Closures